# How can I pass a value from a Groovy script to other build steps in a Jenkins Freestyle Job?

Tags: powershell, jenkins, groovy

I have a step in my Jenkins freestyle job that runs a Groovy script as follows:

```
 import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

 def creds = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
   com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.Credentials.class
 )

 for (c in creds) {
   if (c.properties.username == 'TestUser')
   {
     if (c.properties.description) {
       println("   description: " + c.description)
     }
     if (c.properties.username) {
       println("   username: " + c.username)
     }
     if (c.properties.password) {
      println("   password: " + c.password)
     }
     println("")
  }
}
```

I have another step in my build that runs a PowerShell script.
How can I pass the values *c.description*, *c.username* and *c.password* to the PowerShell script job step?

I don’t want to set environment variables as this will expose the password.

Comment: Make the job parameterized and pass the values from 1 job as input parameters to the other job the moment you trigger that job.

Comment: I actually set a Global Password under Configure System and used that value

Comment: Your primary concern seems to be the password being exposed. If you can't use environment variables I suppose program arguments are out, too, and so is passing the password via files? I think this leaves only standard input, but the PowerShell plugin does not seem to support this.